# How to test default gravatar image locally on Jekyll?

Tags: html, jekyll, gravatar

[Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) allows you to provide a default image for users without gravatars. Using Gravatars on a Jekyll site is easy, but Gravatar requires the default image to be visible externally.

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ page.gravatar }}?size=200&default={{ site.url | append: "/images/default.png" | cgi_escape }}"/>
```

I'm using `site.url` (and escaping it as required using the `cgi_escape` filter) because the image must be externally visible, but obviously during development that is not the case because my machine is not visible on the internet.

How do I test that everything is correct locally (without deploying this to production first)?

*Edit: The site is hosted on github-pages*